# Ruby on Rails - Call controller method from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

Sorry, I have a Rails newbie question.  In my Rails application, how can I call a method defined in my controller from the view?  For example, let's say I wrote a custom method that retrieves stock information.  In my view, I want to have a regular HTML button, that upon clicking, will call my custom method and populate the stock results.

How is that done?  I've looked around and couldn't find a straightforward way to do this.  But I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: There isn't really a "straightforward" way to do this. When a web page is visited, the entire page is generated in advance and sent to the client. This happens before the user even *sees* any buttons, let alone clicks them. If you want to add more things to the page afterward, you'll need to use Javascript running on the client side to perform an AJAX request to fetch the data and add it to the page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

***Edit: I took the question by its title which wasn't what the question was. The answer to the title of your question is at the bottom***

What you want is an ajax request, which is a separate controller action. You'll need:

1. javascript to request a route and populate its DOM object when the button is clicked
2. an action that returns whatever the ajax request was asking for

There are many ways to do this, but if you search for "howto rails ajax" you'll find a gazillion tutorials to help you on your way. One way that I like is called pjax: https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails

***Old answer...***

Declare a `helper_method`, like so:

In your controlller:

```
private
def find_stock
  ...
end
helper_method :find_stock
```

In your view:

```
<% find_stock.each do |stock| -%>
```

Documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method

Comment: Thank you.  I'll take a look at the rails AJAX tutorials.

Comment: The "old" solution was what I was looking for, interestingly enough ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can check the documentation for the [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) view helper

This is one way, of course, you could use the remote option to do this via an AJAX request.